# Update UITableView after background work done

Tags: objective-c, ios7.1

I'm new to iOS developing and have an silly problem
I have an project to parse RSS feed and it all works fine but I tried to fetch images in the background to improve the UI and stuck on how to update the UIImageView in my TableView cells?
Here the code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";
    MyTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.titleLabel.text = [[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"];
    NSString* test = [[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"url"];
    NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc]
                                        initWithTarget:self
                                        selector:@selector(doNow:)
                                        object:test];
    [queue addOperation:operation];
    cell.myImages = theImagePropery;
    return cell;
}
-(void)doNow:(NSString*)myData
{
    NSString* url = myData;
    url = [url stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    NSURL* imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    NSData* imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
    UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:imageData];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(displayImage:) withObject:image waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```

Now in displayImage method I don't know what to do and thats my last try:

```
-(void)displayImage:(UIImage *)myImage{
    [[self tableView] beginUpdates];
   theImageProbery = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage];
    [[self tableView] endUpdates];
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [LazyTableImages](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html) sample.

It's dated, and you can replace the IconDownloader class with NSURLSesssionDataTask, but it will give you the basic idea of how to structure your code.

Comment: Thanks, This example have it all

Answer (score 1):

Do not use the synchronous method `dataWithContentsOfURL` to request network-based URLs.This method can block the current thread for tens of seconds on a slow network, resulting in a poor user experience. Use the NSURLSession methods ( if your are targeting iOS 7 and later).

```
- (NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTaskWithURL:(NSURL *)url completionHandler:(void (^)(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error))completionHandler
```

or use the `NSURLConnection` method (is you are targeting iOS 6 and later).

```
+ (void)sendAsynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request queue:(NSOperationQueue *)queue completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLResponse*, NSData*, NSError*))handler
```

PS : The best is to use open source librairies that handle all this for you ( downloading the images in a background thread, caching,..).

[AFNetworking+UIImageView](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/UIKit+AFNetworking/UIImageView+AFNetworking.h)

Comment: What if I just need to update the table cells what is the code for that out of cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate?